# How to transform tensors with a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-transformations, riemannian-geometry, tensors, spheres

While studying differential geometry, I came across this problem.

When you try to find the metric or the basis vectors of the 2-sphere, you can use the transformation law.

$$e'_i = \frac{dx^j}{dx'^i}e_j$$

And the same with the metric tensor.

However, I can not do this with the Riemann tensor or the Ricci tensor because the not-curved manifold where we have our 2-sphere has vanishing Riemann tensors. In that case, we can not use the transformation rule.

So, when can we use the transformation rule with submanifolds?

Comment: I think the term you're after is "extrinsic curvature tensor". Every time we define something on a manifold in terms of how it is embedded in some larger (usually euclidean) space, we call that property extrinsic.

Comment: I know, but It doesn't mean that we can not deal with riemann tensors, does It?

Comment: Once you have the metric tensor and basis vectors, you can "forget" that they are inherited from the ambient space and calculate the Riemann tensor the normal way.

Comment: It is not clear why it cannot be done...? Coordinates transformation is completely un-related to Riemannian geometry.